What's wrong with cooking shakshuka eggs separately?
If I fry/poach eggs for shakshuka (essentially fried tomato paste with spices) separately, not in tomato sauce dips, will it make any difference to the final result?
In more detail: there is already a question about how to make shashuka and get the eggs cooked without burning the tomato base. I am used to making my shashuka cooking stress-free by cooking the eggs separately. Is there any disadvantage to my method (does it affect the flavour, or perhaps something else I am missing)?
(The image is for the illustration of what this dish looks like. In all three pictures, eggs were cooked in the dips.)


I'm curious, how do you cook the eggs? hard boil, fry, poach, something else?

There is nothing wrong with this approach. In fact, it is a sensible way to ensure the eggs are cooked to your liking...just add them at the end. The only disadvantage is that you have another cooking vessel to clean.

Another difference would be that there is less mixing between the eggs and the tomato sauce. Whether that is a disadvantage or relevant is up to personal preference.

Aside from cleanup, the difference is that you don't get the same end result.  Shakshuka, like other eggs-poached-in-sauce dishes (e.g. eggs Florentine, oeufs en meurette), results in egg whites that have mingled with the sauce some and spread out while cooking.  This integrates the egg better with the sauce: the sauce is eggier and the eggs are more seasoned.
That's a difference, and not a "disadvantage" though; it sounds like you like your eggs to be more separate.  There's nothing wrong with that, it's just different.

I would quibble (with respect)...Since eggs are only added at the last minute, I wonder how much flavor difference you would actually perceive. You are going to eat egg and sauce together either way.  It would make an interest triangle test.

The eggs are cooked in the sauce for 4-7 minutes, so that's plenty of time for them to integrate.  While I've never done a comparison, I've eaten and made shakshuka many times and the result tastes different from "cooked eggs on top of something" to me.  A blind taste test would certainly be interesting though.

IMO the main difference is textural. The acid and the relatively long cooking give the white more firmness and chewiness, even as it spreads out. Fluffy rather than custardy.
